# How to check a user watched the full video in html5 video player without skipping any portion?

Tags: javascript, video, video-streaming, html5-video

We are working on an educational project with content as videos.
Does anyone know how we can check if a video was completely watched or not without skipping any portion? we are using html5 video players:

```
<video width="480" height="400" controls="true" poster="">
    <source type="video/mp4" src="video.mp4"></source>
</video>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check for the video events in html5,
What you need is the `ended` event to check if the video ended,
and the `timeupdate` event to check if the user has skipped some part.

This is a minimal example about what could work, you can take the `skip` object and attach it to the user, and make some analytics with it.

```js
const $video = document.querySelector("video");

const onTimeUpdate = event => {
    console.log(checkSkipped(event.target.currentTime));
}

let prevTime = 0;
const checkSkipped = currentTime => {
  const skip = [];
  // only record when user skip more than 2 seconds
  const skipThreshold = 2;
  
  // user skipped part of the video
  if (currentTime - prevTime > skipThreshold) {
    skip.push({
      periodSkipped: currentTime - prevTime,
      startAt: prevTime,
      endAt: currentTime,
    });
    prevTime = currentTime;
    return skip;
  }
  
  prevTime = currentTime;
  return false;
}

$video.addEventListener("play", e => console.log('play'));
$video.addEventListener("playing", e => console.log('playing'));

$video.addEventListener("timeupdate", onTimeUpdate);

$video.addEventListener("ended", e => console.log('ended'));
$video.addEventListener("pause", e => console.log('pause'));
```

This is a code snippet: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0qrdt2v6/17/)
Helpful links [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37293834/how-to-check-a-user-watched-the-full-video-in-html5-video-player), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events)

Comment: Unless I'm misreading this code, it looks like this code would claim you hadn't watched a video any time you skipped forward more than skipThreshold. What if you had watched a video, rewound to review an earlier section, then skipped forward precisely to where you had been before? This code would unfairly claim you had skipped too much.

Answer (score 4):

You can listen for the `ended` event like the other answer, but instead use the `.played` property of the video element, it has the time ranges the user played, so whenever the user skips some content it pushes a new time range, but if the user has watched the whole video, then it holds only one time range and it will be the first (`"index 0"`), so the point is to subtract the start time from the end time, if it is equal to the duration of the video, then the user has fully watched the video, else some part(s) were skipped, here is a live example

```js
document.querySelector("video").onended = function() {
  if(this.played.end(0) - this.played.start(0) === this.duration) {
    console.log("Played all");
  }else {
    console.log("Some parts were skipped");
  }
}
```

```html
<video src="https://res.cloudinary.com/saymoinsam/video/upload/v1541676544/ABeautifulMind.mp4" controls width="300" height="200"></video>
```